# Update csv column in C

Tags: c, csv

I have the following code which is supposed to read and write to csv file. I want to add update field functionality so I will be able to search and find certain field cell (this is already implemented) and then update (overwrite) field cell next to it.

csv has following configuration:
| town | rss | soc |
|:--: |:--:|:--:|
| LA  | sol | sap |
| BA  | kol | kap |

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// parse csv file to next ","
const char *getfield(char *line, int num)
{
    const char *tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
         tok && *tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char *name;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.csv", "r+");
    int result;
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, fp))
    {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        getfield(tmp, 1);
        // comparing strings str1 and str2
        name = "LA";
        result = strcmp(name, tmp);
        // found required name
        if (result == 0)
        {
            char *tmp2 = strdup(line);
            printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp2, 2));
            // this section should overwrite next column cell to POP
            fprintf(fp, "POP");
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

it should look like this after update
csv has following configuration:
| town | rss | soc |
|:--: |:--:|:--:|
| LA  | **POP** | sap |
| BA  | kol | kap |

Comment: Don't think you can overwrite a field in a text file. You must read the entire file, change what is needed, and write a new file. For one thing, the data would have to be the exact same size. For another the file pointer has advanced, and your `fprintf` won't do what you think. Anyway, C standard *requires* that you position the file pointer when switching between reading and writing, and vice versa.

Comment: Did you copy this by hand? `fp` and `name` are missing their type declarations.